# How to search type datetime in FriendsOfCake/Search plugin?

Tags: search, cakephp-3.1

I did use [FriendsOfCake/Search plugin](https://github.com/friendsofcake/search), everything was fine until i do search created datetime.

When i submit search form, the created variable become to `http://localhost:8765/admin/logs?created=2015%2F10%2F10` and i cannot find any record.

How to search type datetime with [FriendsOfCake/Search plugin](https://github.com/friendsofcake/search)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found another way

Used callback function in search plugin:

In latest version 1.2.3 [FoC Search](https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/search)

```
$this->searchManager()
        ->add('id', 'Search.Value')
        ->add('role_id', 'Search.Value')
        ->add('email', 'Search.like', [
            'before' => true, 
            'after' => true, 
            'field' => [$this->aliasField('email')]
        ])
        ->add('full_name', 'Search.Like', [
            'before' => true, 
            'after' => true, 
            'field' => [$this->aliasField('full_name')]
        ])
        ->add('created', 'Search.Callback', [
            'callback' => function($query, $args, $manager) {
                return $query->andWhere(["Users.created >=" => new FrozenTime($args['created'])]);
            }
        ]);
```

In view, use [datepicker](http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/?markup=input&format=&weekStart=&startDate=&endDate=&startView=0&minViewMode=0&maxViewMode=2&todayBtn=false&clearBtn=false&language=en&orientation=auto&multidate=&multidateSeparator=&keyboardNavigation=on&forceParse=on#sandbox)

[image: View datepicker]

Answer (score 0):

Well, i found the answer.

In FriendsOfCake/search plugin, they support several type of search: value, finder, like, custom, compare.

I choose use define my finder in TableClass like:

```
public function findCreated(Query $query, array $options) {
    if (!empty($options['created'])) {
        return $query->where(['Logs.created >=' => $options['created']]);
    }
    return $query->where(['Logs.created >= (CURDATE() - 10)']);
}
```

Then in i setup searchConfiguration to call findCreated:

```
    public function searchConfiguration() {
    $search->finder('created');
    return $search;
}
```

then, it's work.

If someone have better solution, just post your answer here.

**Thanks.**